# Can I add paintComponents() into an array?

Tags: java, arrays, swing, user-interface, paintcomponent

This is some updated code, I'm still having trouble changing the color of individual rectangles. I want to use an array called spaces[] which has 15 elements, in order to decide where a car should be parked. I'm thinking about somehow comparing the last element of my Rectangle array to compare to the CarSpace array... and then change the color.
Here is my updated code..

```
package carManagement;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class CarPanel extends JPanel 
{
CarSpace[] space= new CarSpace[15];
private final Rectangle[] rects;
private Color shapeColor = Color.RED;

    public CarPanel()
    {

        rects = new Rectangle[]
        {
            new Rectangle(25, 35, 30, 80,"8"),
            new Rectangle(65, 35, 30, 80,"7"),
            new Rectangle(105, 35, 30, 80,"6"),
            new Rectangle(145, 65, 30, 50,"2"),
            new Rectangle(185, 65, 30, 50,"1"),
            new Rectangle(25, 170, 30, 50,"13"),
            new Rectangle(65, 170, 30, 50,"12"),
            new Rectangle(105, 170, 30, 50,"11"),
            new Rectangle(145, 170, 30, 50, "3"),
            new Rectangle(190, 160, 92, 80, "Attendant Station"),
            new Rectangle(25, 280, 30, 50, "15"),
            new Rectangle(65, 280, 30, 50, "14"),
            new Rectangle(105, 280, 30, 80, "10"),
            new Rectangle(145, 280, 30, 80, "9"),
            new Rectangle(185, 280, 30, 50, "5"),
            new Rectangle(225, 280, 30, 50, "4")   

        };

    }//end carPark

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        this.setBackground(Color.white);

        for (int i = 0; i<15; i++) {               

            if(space[i] == null){

                g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                g.drawString(rects[i].number, rects[i].x, rects[i].y);
                g.setColor(Color.GREEN); 
                g.fillRect(rects[i].x, rects[i].y, rects[i].w, rects[i].h);
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("RED SPACESSS");
            }

        }//end for
    }//end paintComponent
}//end JPanel
```

Comment: Please clarify -- where exactly are you stuck? Have you broken your problem down into small steps yet? If so, which step exactly has you hung up? A little more detail can help greatly.

Comment: Also, that code above could be greatly simplified if you used an array or ArrayList and painted things in a for loop. Use a pencil and paper to figure out how to calculate your numbers with that loop since all you'd need would be simple math.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create helper class Rectangle with x,y,w,h and use array of it to paint.

```
public class CarPark extends JPanel {

private final Rectangle[] rects;

static class Rectangle {
    int x,y,w,h;

    public Rectangle(int x, int y, int w, int h) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.w = w;
        this.h = h;
    }

}

public CarPark(){
    rects = new Rectangle[]{
        new Rectangle(25, 35, 30, 80),
        new Rectangle(50, 35, 30, 80)
    };

}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    this.setBackground(Color.white);

    for (Rectangle rect : rects) {
        g.fillRect(rect.x, rect.h, rect.w, rect.h);
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Thanks so much! It's much clearer now, would I be able to select specific rectangle objects and repaint them based on their height and width?

Comment: you can add Color as property to Rectangle and use it to when painting. So first iterate over array of rectangles, find the one that is fine for car, and than change color.

Comment: look into this code (you can copy and run it) https://gist.github.com/anonymous/1ca847a3bdda0011a197

Comment: this is what I need! Thank you, I'm sure it won't be that difficult to add cars to specific rectangle objects by using the sizes given in the parameters.